# Next JS how to Redirect user based on the IP address?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm currently using express and this method inside  app.get('/anyPath') to determine the IP address of the client.

```
var ip = req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
    if (ip.substr(0, 7) == "::ffff:") {
      ip = ip.substr(7)
      console.log(ip)
    }
```

is there a different approach? I find myself repeating the above lines of code in all my app.get() calls to match different paths for the pages.

Comment: Try writing a small middleware for that

Comment: hmm, interesting question since the nextjs has caching layer and server rendering, I think your question should be handled at now layer. I am not 100% sure if there is a solution for that

Comment: I think the incoming version they will include document middleware and you can do it there. taking a look here https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7208 you can have some workaround as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example modified from Express docs [middleware] https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.method === 'get') {
    var ip = req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
      if (ip.substr(0, 7) == "::ffff:") {
        ip = ip.substr(7)
        console.log(ip)
      }
  }
  next()
})
```

Comment: the question is about nextjs, it is not actually express so your solution might not work I think

Comment: just realized I made wrong statement, it is possible to have middleware in nextjs :)

Comment: @ducmai Do you mean that you added this code to `pages/_app.js` file in next.js?
What `app` variable in (`app.use`) refers to? Does it refer to `express` or `next`?

Comment: the code in this answer is from a custom express server so you can read about custom server in next js

Comment: @ducmai I understand, I just needed to confirm if `use()` is member of `app = express()` or `app = next()  // Next.js (not the next callback)`.

Comment: `app.use()` is express not nextjs